# Ransack: boolean attributes are ignored, all records are returned instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I'm using ransack to allow users do dynamical searching:

Controller:

```
@q = Visit.search(params[:q]);
@visits = @q.result(distinct: true)
@q.build_condition
```

Model:

```
def self.ransackable_attributes auth_object = nil
(column_names - UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES) + (_ransackers.keys)
end
```

View:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: doctor_visits_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.condition_fields do |c| %>
    <%= render "condition_fields", f: c%>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add condition", f, :condition %>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search", {:class => "btn"} %></div>
<% end %>
```

Partial:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.attribute_fields do |a| %>
    <%= a.attribute_select({ associations: 
        [:specialists, :treatment_factors]
            },{:class => "form-control"}) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.predicate_select({},{:class => "form-control"}) %>
  <%= f.value_fields do |v| %>
    <%= v.text_field :value,{:class => "form-control"} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "Remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</div>
```

I have several boolean attributes in Visits table. When I choose the boolean attribute in the first field, *true* or *false* in second (*predicate* field) and leave the third *value* field empty, the params are generated correctly, but the sql query is not, the condition is ignored and all the records from the table are returned instead.
What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your model:

Simple version, using PostgreSQL:

```
  ransacker :predicate do
    Arel.sql("to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"predicate\", '99999')")
  end
```

and the same, using MySQL:

```
ransacker :predicate do
  Arel.sql("CONVERT(#{table_name}.id, CHAR(4))")
end
```

Comment: Didn't help. I used `ransacker :bool_test do 
    Arel.sql("to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"bool_test\", '99999')") 
  end`

Comment: which database you have using?

Comment: PostgreSQL   //"Comments must be at least 15 characters in length."

Comment: can you try this  0 for false and  1 for true                                                                                               = select :q, :bool_test_true, [['TRUE', 1], ['FALSE', 0]], { include_blank: 'All', selected: params[:q] ? params[:q][:bool_test_true] : '' }

Comment: where should I put this?

Comment: I have got answer for that